# How do I remove Drupal profile2 module and all user profile tables it created

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have switched to a javascript / api login for front end users and need to delete all of the users in drupal (other than me) and want to find and remove all of the profile field tables that were created for user data.

pm-disable profile2 didn't not do it like I was hoping.

Comment: I think i can manually check all field_* tables for the entity_type but I was hoping there was a drush way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to unistall the module, first disable then go to unistall modules select your module and unistall. 
help here : [Unistalling Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/250783)

The unistall will delete what module created on install. 

 for Drush use : `drush pm-uninstall mymodule`

[Related ask on drupalstack](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/quick-uninstall-reinstall-of-a-custom-module)

Comment: alas the tables were created when the profile fields were added so that didn't work.

Comment: is there a way to have these uninstalled from a script to run when i do drush updb?

Comment: are you shure that unistall then run updb not delete the tables ? i was always think that it does, you could do remove manualy

Comment: yes, I think (not really great at drupal yet) that profile2 uses the field module to install all the additional profile fields as you create new user fields. Just reran drush pm-uninstall profile2 to confirm it was already uninstalled and drush updb to confirm "no db changes required" and still have field_data_field_customer_address_1 with entity_type = profile2

Comment: Yeah, drush cannot delete custom tables you created, so custom field = custom table but you can delete this table, will not have any issue.